# filtering an array of objects that has nested arrays, with an array of values

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array "link" of objects, the objects have a feild that is another array.
Then I have an array "valuesAces" of strings

I would like to filter "links" in order to get the objects that have at least one of the values in "valuesAces".

In the following example ,  "linksFiltered" needs to end up being :

```
[
{aces:['A','B']},{aces:['A','C','D']},{aces:['B']},{aces:['D','B']}
]
```

Example :

```
let links = [
{aces:['A','B']},{aces:['A','C','D']},{aces:['B']},{aces:['D','C']},{aces:['D','B']}
]

let valuesAces = ['A','B']


linksFiltered = links.filter(link => { return 
 [...link.aces].some(ace => valuesAces.includes(ace)
 )})
```

I am apparently doing something wrong as the result is not the one expected.
Any advicewill be very appreciated

Comment: Why are there no commas between objects in your `links` array?

Comment: you have syntax issues. commas missing between array elements in links array. extra closing bracket in the linksFiltered

Comment: `let linksFiltered = links.filter(link => {return [...link.aces].some(ace => valuesAces.includes(ace))})`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const links = [
    {aces:['A','B']},
    {aces:['A','C','D']},
    {aces:['B']},
    {aces:['D','C']},
    {aces:['D','B']}
]

const valuesAces = ['A','B']


const linksFiltered = links.filter(link => link.aces.some(ace => valuesAces.includes(ace)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're missing commas in your `links`

```
let links = [
  {aces:['A','B']},
  {aces:['A','C','D']},
  {aces:['B']},
  {aces:['D','C']},
  {aces:['D','B']}
]
```

Then you had one extra `)` after `.includes(ace))))`. It should be:

```
let valuesAces = ['A','B']

linksFiltered = links.filter(link => { return (
 ([...link.aces].some(ace => valuesAces.includes(ace)))
)})
```

But why are you putting so many parentheses? This is the same code:

```
linksFiltered = links.filter(l => l.aces.some(a => valuesAces.includes(a)))
```

Finally, for better readability, you can change it to:

```
const inValuesAces = x => valuesAces.includes(x) 
 
linksFiltered = links.filter(l => l.aces.some(inValuesAces))
```